# Click coords on resized image in Shiny App doesn't cover full image

Tags: r, image, shiny, imagemagick, shiny-reactivity

My app resizes an image by adding a border. Then, I need to gather click coords anywhere on the modified image with the border. This doesn't seem to work with a dynamically-sized image output.

The code below produces an app where you can see the x coords of a double-click. Notice how without a border, the x coords update for the whole range of the image -- clicking from left to right you see values for the entire range. However, when a border is added, the x coords stop about in the middle and don't update when clicking on the right side of the image.

If I remove the dynamically determined width and height (e.g., `session$clientData$output_img_width`) in the `renderImage`, it works as expected.

Is there a way to have the dynamically-created image size and full click coords?

Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(magick)

img <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")

ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput("border", "Border Size", 0, 100, 0),
    verbatimTextOutput("coords", placeholder = TRUE),
    imageOutput("img",  
                dblclick = "img_dblclick")
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    updatedImageLoc <-reactiveVal(value = NULL)

    observe({
        file.saved.to.disk <- img %>%
            image_border("red",
                         geometry = paste0(input$border * 10,
                                           "x",
                                           input$border * 10)) %>%
            image_write(tempfile(fileext = "test.png"))

        updatedImageLoc(file.saved.to.disk)
    })

    output$coords <- renderText({ paste("Double-click x coord is:",input$img_dblclick$x) })

    output$img <- renderImage({
            # Read width and height. These are reactive values, so this
            # expression will re-run whenever these values change.
            width  <- session$clientData$output_img_width
            height <- session$clientData$output_img_height

            # Return a list
            list(src = updatedImageLoc(), 
                 contentType = paste0("image/png"),
                 width = width,
                 height = height)
        }, 
        ## DO NOT DELETE THE FILE!
        deleteFile = FALSE
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```